# create a multiple table with different rows in a PDF

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, pdf-generation

I want to create a multiple table with different rows in a PDF, in which the data are coming from my iPhone app. How can i do that?

Comment: explain more what you want to achieve with that ..

Comment: To create a multiple table in pdf two row & four columns,five row & four columns like this

Answer (score 0):

Check https://github.com/yfujiki/PDFRenderer
You can pass data from your app to the PDF and draw anything you want.

I use it in old apps, it works fine and easy to use.

Example drawing a string to the PDF using a variable :

```
NSString * stringTest = @Test string to draw in PDF file";
[PDFRenderer drawString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stringTest] withFont:YOUR_UIFONT inRect:CGRECT_FRAME_OF_UILABEL andAlignement:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

The great Raywenderlich tutorial :

https://www.raywenderlich.com/6581/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1

To create different rows just draw lines using the drawLine method, you can also draw image etc.